Why are my yarn dependencies still listed if I deleted node modules
I have a project I am working on and I accidentally downloaded my packages with yarn after running yarn in the terminal.
I deleted the new node_modules folder and then ran yarn list -depth 0 and then received a huge list. Thinking this was just some cache mistake I ran yarn cache clean and then re-ran yarn list -depth 0 and received the same list as earlier. I asked ChatGPT and ran yarn cache dir and went and deleted the file. I again ran yarn list --depth 0 and got the same list. I really don't know what to do. I really don't need a ton of dependencies running around on my laptop. Any help would be appreciated.
I ask this to go straight into file explorer and delete the directory as I really don't have the time to go into terminal and type 'yarn remove pkg-name' for 90+ dependencies.
This is only a third of the huge list I don't have time to use yarn remove for

After you have removed the node_modules. You also need to remove the yarn.lock file. Because all the dependency history is being maintained in this file just like the package_lock in npm.
Only after that you will get the expected output from the commands.

yarn list simply analyses the yarn.lock file generated when installing dependencies.
For example, removing yarn.lock and then running yarn list produces an error...

error No lockfile in this directory. Run yarn install to generate one.

You can rest assured that if you've deleted node_modules, then the dependency files are gone.
